# how can i pass local string value to html code?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a string in same jsp page, how can i set this string as a value in **input type="text"** field,i tried below mention code but it is not working, it is showing null value in input box,
how can i solve this issue, is it any way to solve.

jsp code:

```
<% String a; %>// assume some values to a
<input type="text" value="<%= request.getParameter("a") %>">
```

Comment: **Answer:** step 1: you have to initialize a String as a null between <%!String a=" "%> ,step 2: Then whatever you write in between this <% a=rs.getString(1) %> you can asign this (a)String directly at input value <%= a %>  like that. thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: initialize string value as a null

```
<%! String a="" %>
```

step 2: assign some value to a

```
<% a= "some value" %> // a value will not be null
```

step3: then you can call 'a' directly like this

```
 <input type="text" value="<%=a %>">
```

Comment: a have some value , string a is initialized in while loop at same jsp page. so my problem is i can't access that string directly.

Comment: Does your while loop comes before `<input>` tag? Can you post the loop too? The while loop might not have done the assignment properly.

Comment: how can i call this symbols ( <% %>, <%! %> and <%@ %> )

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<% String a = "some text"; %>// assume some values to a
<input type="text" value="<%= a %>">
```

Comment: Never the less, I would propose you to use <c:out> or similar instead.

Comment: Thank you to quick replay,i tried it before but it is showing error message (local variable may not been initialized) like that.

Comment: i am using eclipse, how can i use <c:out>

Comment: Wait, `local variable may not been initialized` means you did not assign anything to a. Try: `<% String a = "some text"; %>`

Comment: No we can't get that string directly, we have to initialize string before asign value. i wrote answer above in my comment line, thank u.